# HttpSession equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, session-state, httpsession

Below is the code in JAVA written inside a controller. I am saving the cart object inside the HttpSession, so that I can retrieve it always for the same session. Is there any way to do a similar thing in C#?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("in servlet");
    Cart cart = getCartFromSession(request);
}

Cart getCartFromSession(HttpServletRequest req){
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
    Cart cart=(Cart)session.getAttribute("cart");
    if(cart==null){
        cart = new Cart();
        session.setAttribute("cart", cart);
    }
    return cart;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use [`HttpContext.Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.ASPX) Property

To Save:

```
Session["cart"] = cart;
```

To Retrieve:

```
Cart cart = Session["cart"] as Cart;
if(cart != null)
{
   //found
}
```

See: [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.ASPX)